# Jmeter - Distributed(Remote) Test Execution Slave Connection closed in middle of execution

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter version 5.2.1. I have a scenario to simulate 400 parallel logins and inside the test plan I will execute the test samplers for 20 times using loop controller for each users(Threads).

Hence to fast track, I have executed it in remote test execution. Normally 200 Threads with 10 Loop count will take a maximum of 25 mins only. When increasing the loop count to 20, one of the slave node connection closed and the jenkins build went into dead loop.

I am using AWS M5.xLarge instance type. 4 CPU/16 GB RAM.
Below is the run command I am using for Jmeter

```
JVM_ARGS="-Xms2g -Xmx4g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m"  && export JVM_ARGS && ./jmeter -n -t /home/jenkins/workspace/performance-test-staging-pipeline/test_plans/fd_regression_delight.jmx -e -o /home/jenkins/workspace/fd-performance-test-staging-pipeline/Performance-Report -l /home/jenkins/workspace/fd-performance-test-staging-pipeline/JTL-RPT-986.jtl -R xx.xx.xx.xxx,yy.yy.yy.yyy -Jserver.rmi.ssl.disable=true -Dclient.tries=3 -Gthreads=200
```

Below is the build log what I can see in Jenkins build console.

```
summary +   2700 in 00:00:59 =   45.4/s Avg:  3259 Min:    98 Max: 32684 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 400 Started: 400 Finished: 0
summary =  52102 in 00:25:38 =   33.9/s Avg:  6542 Min:    81 Max: 139355 Err:     0 (0.00%)
```

Below is the log I can see in jenkins-server.log

```
Connection to xx.x.x.xxx closed by remote host.
Connection to xx.x.x.xxx closed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using spot instance to run our tests. Once I increase the draining timeout of the security group, my issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into this line:

```
summary =  52102 in 00:25:38
```

it seems that JMeter executed 52102 requests in 25 minutes. I don't know how many requests does your test plan have, however I would expect something like:

- for 1 request: 400 threads * 20 loops * 1 request = 8000
- for 2 requests: 400 threads * 20 loops * 2 requests = 16000
- for 3 requests: 24000 results
- etc.

So make sure you provide correct number of loops or limit your test duration either on [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level or using the [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller)

Also when it comes to [distributed testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter) every slave executes the test plan as it is so if you have 200 users set in the test plan and have 1 slave - you will have 200 users, for 2 slaves you will have 400 users, for 3 slaves - 600 users, etc. so if you need 200 users in total you might want to set `-Gthreads=100` given you have 2 slave machines

Also pay attention to the response time, it seems that for certain samplers it exceeds 2 minutes, 2 minutes * 20 loops gives 40 minutes of total execution

Comment: I can see the Jmeter client still active even after completion. Below are the last 3 lines in jmeter.log 

```2020-11-30 10:05:30,138 INFO o.a.j.r.Summariser: summary +  15800 in 00:00:29 =  553.8/s Avg:   208 Min:     4 Max: 18558 Err: 13375 (84.65%) Active: 250 Started: 250 Finished: 0
2020-11-30 10:05:30,139 INFO o.a.j.r.Summariser: summary =  66827 in 00:25:45 =   43.2/s Avg:  3204 Min:     4 Max: 130746 Err: 13378 (20.02%)
2020-11-30 10:05:35,875 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Finished remote host: 10.0.3.245 (1606730735875)```

How to stop the jmeter after execution completes?

Comment: If you want to stop the remote slave after the test you can define the following property: `jmeterengine.remote.system.exit=true` either in [*user.properties* files](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) or by passing it via [`-J` command line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override). More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Still getting the same issue. Below is the Jmeter Client launch command
```
JVM_ARGS="-Xms10g -Xmx10g" ./jmeter -n -t /home/jenkins/workspace/release-performance-test-staging-pipeline/test_plans/delights/regression.jmx -e -o /home/jenkins/workspace/release-performance-test-staging-pipeline/Performance-Report -l /home/jenkins/workspace/release-performance-test-staging-pipeline/JTL-FD-1002.jtl -R xx.x.x.xxx,yy.y.y.yyy -Jserver.rmi.ssl.disable=true -Dclient.tries=3 -Gthreads=125 -Jjmeterengine.remote.system.exit=true -X
```

Comment: Dmitri, I can see the Slave machine went offline in the middle of execution. We are using Spot Instance. ``` Connection to xx.x.x.xxx closed by remote host.
Connection to yy.y.y.yyy closed. ``` What could be the reason?